# Download Android app download from website - prevent apk from being accessible

Tags: android

My app is accessible through the website. The issue with this is when the user downloads, the apk is accessible to the user. Is there a way to download through the website where the apk is not accessible i.e it gets installed but the user cant get access to the apk for reverse engineering?

Comment: Download to getFilesDir() and use a FileProvider to let the apk be installed.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer - the APK is always accessible.

You cannot protect your app from reverse engineering by preventing access to the APK - this is what's used to 'install' the app on the phone and thus has to be transferred (and remains) on the device.

There are even many free apps on the play store that will extract the APK file from any installed apps on your phone.

If you wish to protect yourself from reverse engineering you need to do it at the code level, the most common techniques are:

1. Code Obfuscation
2. Moving Business Sensitive logic  to a server you control
3. SSL Certificate pinning

and many more.

Answer (score 0):

No. Any installed app can be extracted from the device and decompiled.